# XCode plugin on Jenkins: can I specify -arch to be i386?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, continuous-integration

Is there a way to specify architecture for Jenkins xcode build plugin to be i386, I cannot see a way to do it. An alternative solution is to use unit-test for the purpose as it is using i386, but I don't want to do this workaround.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could also add i386 as a valid architecture in xcode itself. Then xcodebuild will pick that up and also make the ipa valid for i386.